# Why does bazel require me to add dependencies of the library my project is dependent on for Go?

Tags: go, bazel

I am working with the [echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) framework. Hence, my project is directly dependent on `github.com/labstack/echo/v4`. Accordingly, I have added it to my `go.mod` and `WORKSPACE` file. However, bazel build fails and only works if I add the following 2 dependencies.

github.com/labstack/gommon
github.com/valyala/fasttemplate

Why is this required, and is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

These modules are required because they are dependencies of the echo module and therefore required to build the code. See the dependencies listed in [echo's go.mod file](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/bb7f2223bbddee817a1e8a940d186a7328025f6e/go.mod):

```
[...]
github.com/labstack/gommon v0.3.0
github.com/valyala/fasttemplate v1.2.1
[...]
```

Comment: Don't these themselves have further dependencies? Why are we not required to add them as well then? Or rather, in what scenario would I not be required to add dependencies of my dependencies?